# How Can I Determine the Weaved Method?

Tags: postsharp

I have a PostSharp aspect (implemented below as `AutoData`) applied to a test method as such:

`[Theory, AutoData( additionalTypes: typeof(MethodFormatter) )]
    public void MethodFormatsAsExpected( FormatterFactory sut )
    {
        var name = MethodBase
                   .GetCurrentMethod()
                   .Name; // Resolves to "<MethodFormatsAsExpected>z__OriginalMethod"
    }`

As you can see, the result of `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod` is returning the weaved body.  I would like to instead retrieve the (parent) target method that the aspect has weaved, basically the equivalent of:

`var method = GetType()
                 .GetMethod( nameof(MethodFormatsAsExpected) )
                 .Name; // Returns "MethodFormatsAsExpected"`

But in a generic, static way like what `MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod` provides.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By itself, it is not possible to obtain the original method from the code at runtime.

However, you can use aspects to enhance methods in which you need this information and remember in which method you are in a (thread) static stack variable.

Conceptually the following code uses an `AssemblyLevelAspect` that enhances all methods from which you call `CurrentMethodService.Get()` with an internal `MethodLevelAspect` that pushes a current method into the stack when the method is executed and pops it when the method is exiting.

```
public static class CurrentMethodServices
{
    [ThreadStatic]
    private static Stack<MethodBase> slots;

    internal static Stack<MethodBase> Slots
    {
        get { return slots ?? (slots = new Stack<MethodBase>()); }
    }

    public static MethodBase Get()
    {
        return Slots.Peek();
    }

    internal static void Enter(MethodBase slot)
    {
        Slots.Push(slot);
    }

    internal static void Exit()
    {
        Slots.Pop();
    }
}

[PSerializable]
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Assembly, Inheritance = MulticastInheritance.Multicast)]
public class CurrentMethodPolicy : AssemblyLevelAspect, IAspectProvider
{
    public IEnumerable<AspectInstance> ProvideAspects(object targetElement)
    {
        foreach (
            MethodUsageCodeReference methodRef in
                ReflectionSearch.GetMethodsUsingDeclaration(typeof(CurrentMethodServices).GetMethod("Get",
                    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)))
        {
            if ((methodRef.Instructions & MethodUsageInstructions.Call | MethodUsageInstructions.CallVirtual) != 0)
                yield return new AspectInstance(methodRef.UsingMethod, new MethodEnhancement());
        }
    }

    [PSerializable]
    public class MethodEnhancement : IMethodLevelAspect
    {
        [PNonSerialized]
        private MethodBase method;

        public void RuntimeInitialize(MethodBase method)
        {
            this.method = method;
        }

        [OnMethodEntryAdvice]
        [SelfPointcut]
        public void OnMethodEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            CurrentMethodServices.Enter(this.method);
        }

        [OnMethodExitAdvice]
        [SelfPointcut]
        public void OnMethodExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            CurrentMethodServices.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

To use the aspect, just apply it on the assembly.

```
[assembly: CurrentMethodPolicy]
```

A nice side effect of this approach is that the method lookup is quite fast.

Note that you should not use `CurrentMethodServices.Get()` from any other aspect methods, just in the enhanced code.

Also, setting aspect inheritance to `Multicast` forces PostSharp to apply the aspect on referencing assemblies, so you only have to apply it only in the assembly that declares the aspect.

Last, `CurrentMethodServices.Get()` is not going to work when it is used in a project that is not using PostSharp.

Comment: WOW... sorry for the delay in responding to this.  I never got a notification for it.  Very nice work. :)